# How to get the details of a model which is interrelated with another model but not directly related to parent in Laravel4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

The user model of my website look like this

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function answer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Answer','user_id');
    }

    public function supplierranking(){
        return $this->hasMany('Supplierrank','userid','id');
    }
}
```

Now each user will rank a company in a ranking Model which looks like this

```
Class Supplierrank extends Eloquent{
    public function supplier(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Supplier','supplierid','id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User','userid','id');
    }

}
```

I am able to get the user with the ranking details but I also have to get the details of companies that has been ranked from a Supplier table

which looks like this

```
Class Supplier extends Eloquent{
    public function supplierranks(){
        return $this->hasMany('Supplierrank','supplierid');
    }

}
```

My query that I have done looks like this

```
$usersandranking = User::where('event','=',$exceleve)->with('supplierranking')->orderBy('id')->get();
```

It gets me user detail and there rankings but not the supplier names

Can any one help me on this

Comment: Still any confusion?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use `hasManyThrough` relationship. [Laravel documentation says](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent), The `has many through` relation provides a convenient short-cut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation.

For example `User` model might have many `Supplier` through a `Supplierrank` model.

So now you can define a function in your user model to get all supplier using eager loading

```
//In your user model define this function
public function suppliers() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Supplier', 'Supplierrank', 'userid', 'supplierid');
}
```

And you query will now look like something

```
$usersandranking = User::where('event','=',$exceleve)->with('supplierranking')->with('suppliers')->orderBy('id')->get();
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9d18fa16bdc802e7baafaa3b825c6ecfd6da7dd

Comment: i changed the from 'Supplier', 'Supplierrank', to  'Supplierrank','Supplier', and it has given me some data I am checking it now

Comment: @Vikram [Try this one and tell me the output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4f7298dc3912dec039bd3aa583ca66f244c2ffd)

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'suppliers.userid' in 'field list' (SQL: select `supplierranks`.*, `suppliers`.`userid` from `supplierranks` inner join `suppliers` on `suppliers`.`id` = `supplierranks`.`supplierid` where `suppliers`.`userid` = 1380)

Comment: @Vikram Try in foreach this way `$user_ranking->supplierranking->suppliers`

Comment: Its not the foreach bro its the query only the laravel is not able to find the relation between supplier and supplierrank table but i will try you above code

Comment: now I am getting this  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$suppliers

Comment: @Vikram sorry use the `supplier` method instead of `suppliers`

Comment: Please write the code or else i might do some mistake

Comment: I am getting this  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$supplier

Comment: @Vikram http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bb1103aa8d8052e6bdbfba837361f5b6f83f2c8

Comment: the first line is giving me empty object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1342 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: this is the 2nd Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$supplier

Comment: The last approach which will clear all things Just a moment and I will briefly clarify everything

Comment: @Vikram I've explained everything from start to end and if still not fixes your problem then I've no other options [Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d78f81afb6a0dc432493b328ffe071cb9593cbf2).

Comment: I am not getting the suppliers details yet again only ranking is available